# Macro using concatenate with differing numbers of rows in workbooks

Tags: sql, excel, concatenation, vba

I am new to this forum so apologize if I am unable to explain my problem accurately.

I have data in Column B, rows 1-1200 (estimate) in one workbook, which I want to concatenate in Column C of that same workbook.  I know how to do this and create a macro complete this task.

The problem comes in when I have a workbook that has data in Column B, rows 1-2000 (estimate).  When I use my macro, it stops at row 1200.

Is there a way to select Column C for the concatenate function, and have it stop when the data stops in Column B?

Every workbook I use needs the same concatenate function, however, the rows vary in every workbook.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-1], "" "", ""-0000"")"
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B12")
    Range("B2:B12").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: `When I use my macro, it stops at row 1200. ` Can you show us the code?

Comment: Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-1], "" "", ""-0000"")"
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B12")
    Range("B2:B12").Select
End Sub

Comment: It is difficult reading macro in comments. Can you update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying? I have commented the code so you will not have a problem understanding it. Still if you do then post back :)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim col As Long, lRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    '~~> Check if what the user selected is a valid range
    '~~> User has to select the range which
    '~~> has data for example Col B
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Select a range first."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set rng = Selection

    '~~> Ensure that the user doesn't select range with multiple columns
    If rng.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please select only one column or cell"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With ws
        '~~> Get the last row of say Col B
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Identify the column which will have formulas
        col = rng.Column + 1

        '~~> Identify the range which will contain the formulas
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, col), .Cells(lRow, col))

            '~~> Fill formuals in all in one go
        rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-1], "" "", ""-0000"")"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So sorry, but is there any way you could take the comments out.  I'm new at all of this!

Comment: @user3120550: comments are there to help you understand the code. once you understand the code, simply delete them :)  The idea here is not to just give you a solution but to help you understand how it works so that next time when you are stuck, you know what to do :)

Comment: Gotcha...I will try and muddle through.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I offer this as an alternative. If column B ever skips data rows this will guarantee you get a result in column C through the last used row of column B.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim DataRange As Range
  Set DataRange = Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("B:B"))
  DataRange.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-1], "" "", ""-0000"")"
End Sub
```